# How do I use a local variable from one method in the execution of another method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

So basically what I am doing is creating a list of URLs that I am parsing from a specific url...in this case, the base url is the local variable `url`.

What I want to do is, pass `url` to `my_list` - which works fine now...but once I have that list, I then want to pass the first element of the array `list` declared in the method `my_list` to the method `add_category`.

See the code:

```
def add_category(url)
    new_url = url + '/web'  
end

url = 'http://www.someurl.com'

def my_list(url)
    root = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    list = root.css("a").map do |link|
        [link.text, link[:href]]           
      end

end

my_list(url)

add_category(list[0])
```

Where I am going is, I want to modify every single URL in the `list` array per the rules I specify in the `add_category` method.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot refer to method's local variables from outside. They are called "*local*" for a reason! :)

It seems that your `my_list` method is simply generating a list that you want to use later. So, save its return value to a local variable (in the caller scope) and use however you want. Check this out:

```
def add_category(url)
    url + '/web'  
end

url = 'http://www.someurl.com'

def my_list(url)
    root = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    root.css("a").map do |link|
        [link.text, link[:href]]           
    end
end

list = my_list(url)

new_url = add_category(list[0][1])
```

Comment: I am getting a 'can't convert String to Array' error around the `url + '/web'` line. Thoughts?

Comment: Your `url` is an Array, not a String (as you'd think). Put some debug printing to your script to understand what's going on.

Comment: Ahhh.....you are right. I figured it out...but why would `url` be an array? Isn't just doing `url = 'some string` make `url` a strong, not an array?

Comment: I fixed this one for you, but you should learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: I actually fixed it by doing `url.first + '/web'` which allows me to access `list[0]`. But I still don't understand why `url` was an array when I declared it as a string.

Comment: You didn't declare `url` anywhere. It's passed as a parameter. And that parameter comes from your `my_list` function that generates array of arrays `[link.text, link[:href]]`.

Comment: I did declare `url = 'http://www.someurl.com'`...right before `my_list` method definition.

Comment: Ah, right. Well, that url and url in `add_category` are two completely different things.

Comment: Ahhh....I see...I should probably name it something else - because it is confusing me :| Thanks though.